# What exactly does this error indicate?

Tags: java

[image: here is picture of error]

so in my constructor it has two objects as parameters and they are being assigned to variables. Do I need to check if they are null?

Comment: assignment won't need a null check. if those variables are used further then yes , you need a null check.

Comment: Take a lok at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: okay well my consturctor is public Construct(OBJ x, OBJ y) this.x = x; this.y=y; SO I would need to check if it is null Im assuming. My private attributes are objects as well

Answer (score 0):

Simple initialization will not given null pointer exception ,it will give null pointer exception when you are to use that variable or trying to get some value from that variable which is actually null.

```
 For ex:
     String foo = null;
     int length = foo.length();  // HERE
```